# Why won't this ReSharper File Template expand as I expect?

Tags: resharper

I have setup this File Template in ReSharper 7.0.1

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MyProject.Infrastructure.Messaging;

namespace $NAMESPACE$
{
    public class $CLASS$Command : ICommand<$CLASS$Command.Result>
    {
        $END$

        public class Result
        {

        }
    }


    public class $CLASS$Handler : ICommandHandler<$CLASS$Command, $CLASS$Command.Result>
    {
        public $CLASS$Command.Result Process($CLASS$Command c)
        {

            var result = new $CLASS$Command.Result {};
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

When I create a file based on the template, only some of the `$CLASS$` variable instances are populated correctly. In the instances where `$CLASS$` is used in `$CLASS$Command.Result`, `$CLASS$` is replaced with the letter `a` instead of the expected value, like so.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using MyProject.Infrastructure.Messaging;

namespace MyProject.Domain.AnEntity.Commands
{
    public class Test2Command : ICommand<aCommand.Result>
    {


        public class Result
        {

        }
    }


    public class Test2Handler : ICommandHandler<Test2Command, aCommand.Result>
    {
        public aCommand.Result Process(Test2Command c)
        {

            var result = new aCommand.Result {};
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot see a reason why this isn't working. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Your template works with ReSharper 5.1.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This apparently is a bug in certain versions of ReSharper, and is currently in the queue for a fix as best I can tell.

http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RSRP-334501

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `$END$` before `>`.

`public class $CLASS$Command : ICommand<$CLASS$Command.Result$END$>`

This works for me as workaround (R# 7.1.3).

Comment: That makes the one instance (immediately preceding $END$) of $CLASS$Command.Result fill in correctly, but the other two instances later in the doc still are output as "aCommand.Result". I get some marginally different results if I put $END$ in different places, but I have yet to discover a place for $END$ that causes all instances to output correctly.